# NestJs v10 Error: Cannot find module 'src/app.module'

Tags: nestjs, swc-compiler

I just install NestJs v10 and have an error when start

```
> nest start --watch

>  SWC  Running...
Successfully compiled: 4 files with swc (14.34ms)
Watching for file changes.
Error: Cannot find module 'src/app.module'
Require stack:
- /Volumes/NestJs/dist/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/NestJs/dist/main.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)

✔  TSC  Initializing type checker...
>  TSC  Found 0 issues.
```

this is **"nest-cli.json"** file

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "builder": "swc",
    "typeCheck": true
  }
}
```

this is **"tsconfig.json"** file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

I'm using Nest v10.2.3 and Node v18.16

I try change "baseUrl": "./" to "baseUrl": "./src" but still not work

Comment: Can you show your `main.ts` and screenshot of your project structure?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `tsconfig.json`

```js
"compilerOptions":{
  "paths": {
        "*": [
          "*",
          "src/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

In this case, NestJS will handle the configuration of SWC Options and you don't need a explicit separate `.swcrc` file.

They should probably update their docs instead of assuming everyone already knows or just add the paths manually while a project is bootstrapped using their `@nestjs/cli`.