# SWC is not compiling prisma folder

Tags: typescript, nestjs, swc-compiler

I'm developing a Nest.js app and I want to use the SWC for the first time.
I followed the Nest.js docs instructions ([+](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swc)), but I've got an error.

I'm using Prisma in my project and I've created a folder `prisma` in the root directory, with the same level as `src`.
The folder structure is like this:

```
ROOT DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:
.
├── prisma
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── prisma.service.ts
│   └── schema.prisma
├── src
│   ├── common
│   ├── config
│   ├── modules
│   ├── types
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── metadata.ts
│   └── schema.gpl
├── bun.lockb
├── nest-cli.json
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── tsconfig.build.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

I want the folder structure of `dist` to be the same as the root directory after compilation with SWC (i.e. the `prisma` and `src` are both compiled and on the same level) but I'm getting this:

```
DIST DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:
.
├── common
│   └── decorators
├── config
│   ├── environment.config.js
│   ├── environment.config.js.map
│   ├── index.js
│   └── index.js.map
├── modules
│   ├── auth
│   ├── comments
│   ├── posts
│   └── users
├── app.module.js
├── app.module.js.map
├── main.js
├── main.js.map
├── metadata.js
├── metadata.js.map
└── tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo
```

Only the `src` is compiled and is all I can find in `dist`.

Here's the `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

Here's the `.swcrc`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/swcrc",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "decorators": true,
      "dynamicImport": true
    },
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "minify": false
}
```

Here's the script I use to run the project with:

```json
scripts: {
  "start:swc": "dotenv -e .dev.env -- nest start -b swc -w --type-check",
}
```

Since `prisma` directory is not compiled, the runtime can't import anything from it inside `src`, and hence the error:

[image: the error after compilation]

When I run the project without SWC, everything works OK.

I've tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77131982/14191153), and it fixed the starting path of import (`prisma/` to `../../../prisma/`).

Why isn't SWC compiling the `prisma` folder?

Runtime and tools:

- Bun - `1.0.7`
- Nest.js - `10.0.0`
- `@swc/cli` - `0.1.63`
- `@swc/core` - `1.3.96`

Comment: Did you happen to solve this problem?

Comment: @BernalCarlos unfortunately no, I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

For SWC to compile the prisma folder, you need to compile such folder explicitly after the nest build:

`nest build && swc prisma --out-dir dist`

Comment: This is not as fast as it should be, because of `nest build`. Wouldn't it better to set a new script like `swc prisma --out-dir dist/prisma && swc src --out-dir dist/src`? This would compile faster.

Comment: Could be, I don't know. The solution I proposed actually compiled my whole project in 250ms. So I didn't bother to tests other alternatives